# Unable to run my C# .net 2.0 application from a network machine. How to make it fail gracefully?

Tags: c#, networking, reportviewer

Tried out many things to run my application from a network location but nothing worked except increasing the Zone security for Internet Zone in the local machine to Full Trust using Microsoft .net framework 2.0 configuration.

Hence now I am trying to at least handle the error that occurs when I try to run the application from a network location and make it fail gracefully. But I am not able to do this also as the catch block, at the beginning of my code, where I am demanding fulltrust is not being executed at all.
Can somebody suggest a way to do this?

My application uses Microsoft Report Viewer.

Comment: I don't understand what are you trying to achieve and what is your problem

Comment: Im sorry if i sound rude, but your title & question does not make ANY sence WHATSOEVER.

Comment: @sniperX: It does actually. He's asking about the environment needing to "trust" his program before it runs it (I think so, anyway). Just because you don't understand it, doesn't mean nobody will :P

Comment: @silky: he updated his question since i posted my comment

Comment: @all above: My apologies, I had indeed updated the post after sniperX's comment but forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 1):

In your Program.cs file is a line that starts the application, similar to the following:

```
Application.Run(new Form1());
```

You can, instead, replace it with the following:

```
try
{
    Application.Run(new Form1());
}
catch (SecurityException)
{
    // inform the user that they are not set up to run this application
}
```

This *should* catch any Full Trust issues that arise.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Michael. 
I had tried this out but still control is not entering this try block and the application is failing.

Comment: That's very strange; I use that mechanism for one of my applications. Do you have any lines prior to the Application.Run in your code?

Comment: Yes Micheal, a few variable declarations are there.

Comment: Well, that wouldn't make any difference with this issue. What exactly is the error message that's produced when you try to start your application?

Comment: It says that my app has encountered a problem and needs to close. The error report contents show that the error code is 0xe0434f3d.